# How create an Hibernate EntityManager with customized Mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm interested in using Hibernate with dynamic mapping and by that I mean the mapping should not rely on xml or Java classes (Beans or POJO). I've been looking for it and found an explanation on how to programmaticaly create a mapping with Java using the Configuration object to set up the mapping.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

Mappings mappings = configuration.createMappings();
```

Further info on how to do the mapping can be found [here](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically), a nice post by Alessio Stalla.

With the mapping done I'm able to get a session...

```
SessionFactory sf = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()  
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .build());

Session s = sf.openSession();
```

But I haven't found a way to get an EntityManager from this session,
although I found how to get the session from an EntityManager:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("entityManager");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Session s = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
```

Thanks in advance!